# Need an OpenCL library that works under QEMU

Tags: opencl, qemu

I am unsure to put it up, but I need an OpenCL library that can actually work under QEMU.
I have tried NVidia, and AMD but none of them seem to function there.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Intel's or AMD's libs, they both run on the CPU.

Comment: Thanks, I am again trying with AMD sdk, Intel SDK doesn't seem to work without SSE4.1 CPU flags, which I am unable to get on my existing qemu vm setup.